# Display Thumbnail UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmovieplayer

After requesting to generate my thumbnail how would I show it in a UIImageView?

```
 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_videoPathString] ;
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[moviePlayer requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f]] timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The `requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:` method will post a `MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification` notification when an image request completes.

Your code that needs the thumbnail image should subscribe to this notification using **NSNotificationCenter**, and use the image when it receives the notification.

Example.

First register for the **`MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification`** notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then request the thumbnail:

```
[movie requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:YOUR_TIMES timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
```

And then get the image:

```
-(void)handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    UIImage *image = [userInfo valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
}
```

Source: [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes%3atimeOption%3a)

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to make sure that the video doesn't actually play in the background, but just grabs the thumbnail?

Comment: i am getting warnings of constraints before handleThumbnailImageRequestFinishNotification call by ios:

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

 (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
......
......
......

Answer (score 0):

It's very clearly mentioned in the method's documentation:

> This method processes each thumbnail request separately and
>   asynchronously. When the results for a single image arrive, the movie
>   player posts a MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification
>   notification with the results for that image. Notifications are posted
>   regardless of whether the image capture was successful or failed. You
>   should register for this notification prior to calling this method.

to register for a notification, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-98481-BABHDIGJ)